# Calling Saxon-JS function or template from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xslt, saxon-js

I use [C3](https://c3js.org/) to render graphs in an HTML page that uses Saxon-JS and a (compiled, SEF) XSL stylesheet.
C3 generates an SVG image (a bar chart), and provides a possibility to respond to click events on parts of the chart (e.g., a bar), with an onclick function.

```
c3.generate(
  { bindto: ...
  , data:
    { type: 'bar'
    , columns: c3_columns
    , onclick: function(data, element) { ... }
    }
    ...
  })
```

I would like to process the click event in my XSL stylesheet.
However:

- The onclick function is not a JavaScript event handler in the usual sense. The `data` parameter contains data but is not an `Event` instance. Also, the JavaScript `event` variable is `undefined` in the body of the onclick function.
- When I dispatch a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) from the onclick function, I can not handle it in my XSL. That means that when I define `<xsl:template match="*" mode="ixsl:onchartclick">`, this template is not called when I dispatch a `chartclick` event from the onclick function.
- Next, I tried to call a function defined in my XSL stylesheet:
  `<xsl:function xmlns:chart="chart" name="chart:click">`
  This is called from the onclick function (JavaScript) like

  ```
    SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate("chart:click('hello chartCLick')", [],
        { namespaceContext: {'chart' : 'chart'}
        });
  ```

  Although the onclick function is called, the XSL function isn't; All I get in the browser console is "Unknown function Q{chart}click()".

This scenario is a bit complex, but I will include two simplified code samples that hopefully show what I am trying to do.

In the Javascript I have the onclick handler.

```
function chartClickHandler(data, element) {
  // Show the contents of the data.
  console.log(`Click on chart`);
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(`  ${k} : ${v}`));
  // Send a custom event.
  const event = new CustomEvent('chartclick', data);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
  // Call a function in the XSL stylesheet.
  SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`chart:click('hello chartCLick')`, [],
    { namespaceContext: {'chart' : 'chart'}
    });
}
```

This is called from the HTML. For simplicity, I don't use C3, but:

```
<button onclick="chartClickHandler({x: 1, y: 2}, this)">test</button>
```

In the XSL stylesheet that is given to Saxon-JS I have:

```
  <xsl:template match="body" mode="ixsl:onchartclick">
    <xsl:if test="$show-debug-messages">
      <xsl:message>
        Chartclick event properties: <xsl:value-of select="ixsl:eval('Object.keys') => ixsl:apply([ixsl:event()])"/>
      </xsl:message>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function xmlns:chart="chart" name="chart:click">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:message>
      Chart click data: <xsl:value-of select="serialize($data)"/>
    </xsl:message>
  </xsl:function>
```

As said before, all I get is

```
Click on chart debugger eval code:3:11
  x : 1 debugger eval code:4:52
  y : 2 debugger eval code:4:52
Uncaught 
Object { message: "Unknown function Q{chart}click()", stack: ...
```

This example still involves many parts, but the essence of my question is in the title:
How to call a Saxon-JS function or template from JavaScript. Or how to intercept custom events.

Comment: So the SVG is created without Saxon-JS by that C3 library, i.e. with JavaScript? Do you know or control the SVG generated? Can you  decorate or is such bar decorated with some id or class so that you could use/generate an event handler directly with XSLT/SEF? As for calling a function in an XSLT/SEF, I would think you need `SaxonJS.transform({ initialFunction: 'Q{chart}click', functionParams : ['hello chartCLick'], .. })`, see https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/transform.

Comment: Thank you, Martin! I have little control over the generated SVG. Capturing the click is difficult, as C3 uses some tricky code to capture the click before it reaches the SVG element that I (seem to) click on. In this way, C3 can provide to the onclick function the input data that was used to make the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I think to call a function in an SEF you should use `SaxonJS.transform({ initialFunction : 'Q{namespace-uri}function-name', functionParams: [function arguments here], ..}, ..)`.

Example is e.g. https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2022/xsltFunctionCallTest2.html

Content:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Saxon-JS 2 test</title>
    <script src="../../Saxon-JS-2.3/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
    <script>
    var internalStylesheet;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      var options = { 
        stylesheetLocation : 'xsltFunctionCallTest1.xsl.sef.json',
        sourceLocation: 'sample1.xml',
        destination: 'appendToBody'
      };
      SaxonJS.transform(options, 'async').then(result => { internalStylesheet = result.stylesheetInternal; console.log(internalStylesheet); console.log(result); });
    });
    </script>
    <script>
      function functionCallTest1() {
       SaxonJS.transform({ destination: 'raw', stylesheetLocation : 'xsltFunctionCallTest1.xsl.sef.json', initialFunction: 'Q{http://example.com/mf}f1', functionParams: [ { x: 1, y: 'foo' }] }, 'async').then(result => console.log(result.principalResult)); 
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

where the first transform generates e.g.

```
<section>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <p>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</p>
  <input type="button" value="test"
    onclick="functionCallTest1();"/>
</section>
```

Caveat: in the XSLT, make sure you have `visibility="public"` on the XSLT `xsl:function` declared.

Comment: Thank you, Martin! Your solution works. The only drawback seems to be, that `SaxonJS.transform()` in `function functionCallTest1()` loads 'xsltFunctionCallTest1.xsl.sef.json' again. This sef-file was already loaded to generate the page. That is why I thought I might be able to use `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate()`.

Comment: @rakensi, I know of the problem, according to the docs the first call should return some property `stylesheetInternal` with a "cached" stylesheet you should be able to reuse on further calls but somehow for me that property always ends up empty/undefined, so my initial attempt at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2022/xsltFunctionCallTest1.html to reuse it fails. I would hope the browser at least uses its cache for the reload so that it doesn't matter that much. Other than that I don't know how to improve it, someone from Saxonica might be able to tell more.

Comment: Thanks again, Martin. I was also looking for `stylesheetInternal`, and for me it is the only property of the result of `SaxonJS.transform` that is not `null` or `undefined`. It may be what I will end up using. I have been experimenting with `SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate`. The docs [https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate] say "Its use does not require a compiled XSLT stylesheet (SEF) to be loaded", but it also seems to be unable to use functions defined in the loaded stylesheet (even when `visibility="public"`).

Comment: @rakensi, in my understanding the SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate API is rather meant to provide stand-alone XPath 3.1 in the browser, like I do in e.g. https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/, it is not meant to interact with a stylesheet already loaded.